# Profiling of a TypeScript Node.js application

Tags: node.js, typescript, profiling, ts-node

I am looking for a tool to make the profiling of a TypeScript Node.js application, and this without modifying the whole code source.

I mean by profiling: launching the application using some specific tool, which outputs the result like this:

Method        | consumed memory     | consumed time

a()           | 1024                | 20ms
….

I did some internet research and I have found this one: https://github.com/screepers/screeps-typescript-profiler

But using it, I'm obliged to edit the whole code (by adding the @Profiler decorator), I'm looking for something to detect the methods automatically.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

**You can use [WebStorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) for V8 CPU and Memory Profiling.** Here is a guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/v8-cpu-and-memory-profiling.html.

There is no need to change any part of your code. You can run **V8 Profiling**, take **Heap Snapshots** and view useful **snapshot diffs**.

You can use the default Webstorm guide, however, for Node 12 there is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41341) and you will get an error in CLI: `bad option: --log-timer-events`.

For Typescript project with Express and Socket.io server, I use it with [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) tool which simply passes all unknown params to `ts-node` and then to `node`. So, you can apply the same approach when using `ts-node`. **Set `--prof` and `--logfile=logfile-profiling.log` arguments manually**. Here is my example configuration:

[image: Run configuration]

**Disable Record CPU profiling info** to avoid the bug (we set --prof and --logfile manually) and enable **Allow taking heap snapshots**.

[image: V8 Profiling configuration]

Then **run Debug for this configuration**. To take a new heap snapshot click to a bottom icon of a left side panel while debugging your app:

[image: Heap snapshot icon in the bottom]

Heap Snapshots and CPU profiling logs will be stored in your project folder and you can analyze them from menu **Tools > V8 Profiling > Analyze V8 Heap Snapshot** as well as for CPU logs: **Analyze V8 Profiling logs**. CPU profiling logs are created in intervals, so you can run your app and open new logs at the same time.

Comment: at least ```--log-internal-timer-events``` still working