# Profile performance on Heroku with Node JS? (with Typescript, fwiw)

Tags: node.js, heroku, latency

I've looked through Google search results and Stackoverflow, but I can't find a clear solution to this problem. I want to profile a running Node JS web server on Heroku to identify the slow parts. This is a hobby project, so I'm a little reluctant to spend *too much* on a vendor solution.

The post [Profiling of a TypeScript Node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467747/profiling-of-a-typescript-node-js-application) suggested  https://github.com/screepers/screeps-typescript-profiler. Is that my best option?

Comment: Here I was looking for the same option, and found my own post. Alas.